# Section doesn't start from Landscape orientation page

Tags: sectioning, formatting, landscape, thesis, sharelatex

I have tables inserted in the starting of the section in landscape orientation, however the new section shows up only when a portrait page is in use. How should I fix this problem? The following is the link of the zip file wherein I am using ULL thesis class: https://interval.louisiana.edu/thesis-class/ULL-thesis-class-explanation.html

[image] Section 5.2 starts on portrait page (Pg. 406)
[image] However section should start from Pg. 216. All pages before pg. 406 are landscape pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%%landscape table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{everypage}
\newcommand{\Lpagenumber}{\ifdim\textwidth=\linewidth\else\bgroup
  \dimendef\margin=0 %use \margin instead of \dimen0
  \ifodd\value{page}\margin=\oddsidemargin
  \else\margin=\evensidemargin
  \fi
  \raisebox{\dimexpr -\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-0.5\linewidth}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \margin+\textheight+\footskip}%
    \llap{\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}%
\egroup\fi}
\AddEverypageHook{\Lpagenumber}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{trial1}
\author{Abhijeet Chodankar}
\date{June 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
   \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
   \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
       \centering % Center table
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $1.6*10^5$, $1.6*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{13}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.242}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P = \\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & constant & increase & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & constant & decrease & constant & decrease \\ \hline
4 & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $2.4*10^5$, $2.4*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{13}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.243}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P = \\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & constant & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
            \end{landscape}
   \clearpage% Flush page
}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{zero_papercutbalance.PNG}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The figures are printed on portrait page. Since the section was started prior the tables were inserted and figures appear after the tables are placed, the section starts on the portrait page

Comment: please provide small but complete document which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I have elaborated and edited the question now

Comment: sorry, this is only image of your document fragment, not code of document. this is not very helpful. we need **short** code beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` with some dummy text and tables, which we can compile.

Comment: I won't be able to insert the entire code from documentclass since its a very large document. I have added a snippet of the code to elaborate the problem clearly.

Comment: we dont need complete document. just smll one with dummy text generated for example by `lipsum` package`  which demonstrate your problem. also table should be dummy with only few rows and columns. this document should be complilable. sorry, but your code sniped is not. off-topic, don't use floats option `[H]`. it can be source of many troubles in document formatting.

Comment: I have added a simple example of it now

Comment: you have put the landscape table in `\afterpage` so it will be inserted after the current page is filled with normal text but in this example you have no text. As I said on your previous question you do not want `\afterpage` or `\clearpage` here.

Answer (score 2):

to long that can be comment ...

- with small, but complete document, it is called *minimal working example: mwe*, is expected a document's code which looks like the following:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \usepackage{afterpage}

  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}
  \section{first section}
  \lipsum[1-3]

  \section{second section}
  \afterpage{
  \begin{landscape}
      \begin{table}[htb]
  \caption{My landscape table}
      \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{8}{c|}}
      \hline
  1   &   2   &   3   &  4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   \\
      \hline
      \end{tabular*}
      \end{table}
  \end{landscape}
  }
  \lipsum[4-5]
  \begin{figure}[htb]
      \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
  \caption{image which follows landscape table}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[6-7]

  \end{document}
  ```
- please test this code and wee, if it gives result as you expected. if not, please describe, how result should differ from your expectation.
- table on landscape page is inserted immediately after section title, which is on the portrait oriented page
- in result, table is on new page, however after section tile is text which in code is after table.
- here can arise mess, if you have immediately after table on landscape page a figure and if for it is not enough space after section title to be placed immediately after it. in such a case image will be placed after section title but on the new page before landscape page.
- **note**: *anything outside of landscape environment can not appear in its inside*. landscape environment *always start on the new page*.

Comment: Say if the page before the new section begins is filled completely. The section should start on landscape page as the table is inserted before the figure. Since the previous page had some space left, the section got printed on the portrait page in your sample code.

Comment: no, it is not in `landscape` environment! anything outside of `landscape` can not appear in it inside. and `landscape` always star new page.

Comment: This clears my doubt. Thanks a ton, Zarko!!!!! I really appreciate your help and for your valuable time.

Comment: @Abhijeet, if this answer help you, you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at the top left side of the answer).

Comment: My reputation points is below 15, hence it doesn't allow me to vote. Thanks Zarko!!

Comment: @Abhijeet,  not anymore. however, you can accept answer with reputation below 15  :-)